# Error: object '' not found with `separate()`

Tags: r

Some data to reproduce:

```
x <- dput
structure(list(id = 1:10, shift_map = c("main=1.0", "main=1.0", 
"nip=0.05466237942122187, episode=0.19292604501607716, main=0.6270096463022508, cooking=0.09003215434083602, VIP=0.03536977491961415", 
"main=1.0", "main=1.0", "main=1.0", "main=1.0", "main=1.0", "main=1.0", 
"main=1.0")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Looks like:

```
 x
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id shift_map                                                                                                     
   <int> <chr>                                                                                                         
 1     1 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 2     2 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 3     3 nip=0.05466237942122187, episode=0.19292604501607716, main=0.6270096463022508, cooking=0.09003215434083602, V…
 4     4 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 5     5 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 6     6 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 7     7 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 8     8 main=1.0                                                                                                      
 9     9 main=1.0                                                                                                      
10    10 main=1.0
```

I wouldlike to separate shift_map column into new fields based on the name value pairs. Tried:

```
x %>% separate(cols = shift_map, into = c("shift_category", "shift_value"), sep = "=")
Error: object '' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `cols`

Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I overcome this error and split column shift_map into new columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `col` instead of `cols` as the `Usage` of `?separate` is

> separate(
> data,
> col,
> into,
> sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+",
> remove = TRUE,
> convert = FALSE,
> extra = "warn",
> fill = "warn",
> ...
> )

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
   separate(col = shift_map, 
       into = c("shift_category", "shift_value"), sep = "=", extra = "drop")
```

---

If we need to have multiple rows for each 'id' as there are are some 'ids' with multiple sets of 'shift_map', then use `separate_rows` first

```
x %>% 
   separate_rows(shift_map, sep=",\\s*") %>%
   separate(col = shift_map, 
       into = c("shift_category", "shift_value"), sep = "=", 
            extra = "drop", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 14 x 3
#      id shift_category shift_value
#   <int> <chr>                <dbl>
#1     1 main                1     
#2     2 main                1     
#3     3 nip                 0.0547
#4     3 episode             0.193 
#5     3 main                0.627 
#6     3 cooking             0.0900
#7     3 VIP                 0.0354
#8     4 main                1     
#9     5 main                1     
#10    6 main                1     
#11    7 main                1     
#12    8 main                1     
#13    9 main                1     
#1    10 main                1
```